# Categorizing mixed interface results

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface:

```
public inteface IMethods
{
   // More than 200 signatures go here
}


public interface IParams
{
   // Only 5 - 10 signatures go here
}
```

Both of the above interfaces are being merged into a wider interface:

```
public interface IFunctionality : IMethods, IParams
```

Everything works fine but here's the tricky part: I would like upon calling the `IFunctionality` interface to receive a categorization like that:

```
IFunctionality.MethodM1
IFunctionality.MethodM2
...
IFunctionality.MethodM200
IFunctionality.Params.MethodP1
IFunctionality.Params.MethodP2
...
IFunctionality.Params.MethodP10
```

Note the `Params` in the in the above exposure of the `IParams` interface.

Is there a way to achieve this? I haven't tried anything because I don't seem to get how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get would be to declare property typed as `IParams` called `Params`:

```
public interface IFunctionality : IMethods
{
    IParams Params { get; }
}
```